# Populating a field when choosing a relate field _ suite crm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

i'm using suite crm 7.7.5

when i create an opportunity and i choose an account from a relate field, i want a field (country) to be auto populated with the value of the country of the account chosen.

for this, i tried to add the code

```
    $dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['country_c']['populate_list']= array('id','name','country_c');
$dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['country_c']['field_list'] = array('account_id_c','account_name','country_c');
```

in the file \custom\Extension\modules\Opportunities\Ext\Vardefs\sugarfield_country_c.php

knowing that country_c is the name of the column country in the table accounts and  the second country_c  is the id of the field country in the layout opportunity

but that doesn't work, could someone help me to figure out the reason?

PS : i've tried to follow this tutorial https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/08/31/howto-using-a-relate-field-to-populate-a-custom-field/

Comment: Looks like people in this link are saying it doesn't work with the standard modules, so that might explain it: https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2012/06/20/autopopulate-other-fields-based-on-quicksearch-result/

Comment: the article is talking about quicksearch, i'm looking for autopopulating a field, in the editview of opportunity, after choosing the name of an account in a popup

Comment: For anyone coming across this in the future in SuiteCRM 8+ there is a way to do this see [here](https://docs.suitecrm.com/8.x/developer/extensions/frontend/logic/field-logic/fe-extensions-update-value-backend/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to custom/modules/{YOUR MODULE}/metadata/editviewdefs.php and edit editviewdefs.php file.
First you need to find array in which your relate field(account_name) is defined. It will look similar to this, maybe with some more parameters.

```
array (
    'name' => 'account_name',
),
```

Now you need to map data from relate field(country_c) to new field(lets say populated_country_c). After editing your array will look something like this.

```
array (
    'name' => 'account_name',
    'displayParams' => array (
        'field_to_name_array' => array(
            'id'=>'account_id_c',
            'name'=>'account_name',
            'country_c' => 'populated_country_c',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Now `populated_country_c` is the new field in which the data about country will be populated when you choose account in the relate field. So we also need to create that new field. You can do it through studio or manually just by adding new array. Finally your file will look like this

```
array (
        'name' => 'account_name',
        'displayParams' => array (
            'field_to_name_array' => array(
                'id'=>'account_id_c',
                'name'=>'account_name',
                'country_c' => 'populated_country_c',
                ),
            ),
        ),
array (
        'name' => 'populated_country_c',
        'label'=> 'LBL_POPULATED_COUNTRY'
        ),
```

Now when choosing new account from relate field, `populated_country_c` will be populated with `country_c` field from selected account.

Comment: it worked and the field is auto populated but when i try to save the opportunity i got this message "No match for field: Account Name"

Comment: in the navigator i found this piece of code when inspecting the Account Name field  var _form = document.getElementById('EditView'); 
_form.action.value='Save'; if(check_form('EditView'))
SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);return false;  Do someone know where to find the function check_form?

Comment: I had the same error. This is SuiteCRM bug and can be fixed if you name your field in a certain way. Maybe try by adding some numbers. I will try to find my code where i fixed this and will post to you

Comment: When i use  'id'=>'account_id_c' the auto population works fine, but i cannot save. When i use  'id'=>'account_id' the autopopulation doesn't work but i can save the new opportunity

Answer (score 1):

Here is the extension on @Bozic solution.

If someone is trying to autopopulate related fields based on selection then here is the solution. (Those who are facing "No match for field: Account Name")

Scenario: I have Account Owner (relate to User module) field in Accounts module. And in Cases module I am fetching Account owner fields based on Account selection.

In /custom/modules/Cases/metadata/editviewdefs.php

```
 0 => array(
             'name'=>'account_name',
             'displayParams' => array (
             'field_to_name_array' => array(
             'id'=>'account_name',
             'assigned_user_name' => 'account_owner_case_c', 
             'assigned_user_id' => 'user_id2_c',
         ),
     ),
  ),
```

Note:

- assigned_user_name is field id of Account owner from Accounts module
- assigned_user_id is id field of Account owner
- account_owner_case_cis field of Case Account Owner from Case module
- account_name is selection field from case module (on selection of this field account owner will get populate)

Answer (score 0):

Use field *billing_account_country* rather than *country_c*, and also use *account_id* with *account_name*. The name and the id have to coincide to the same table, I believe.