# field_to_name_array - Take second-level related data

Tags: php, customization, crm, suitecrm, related-content

I'm in a custom module; in editview.

Thanks to this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063014/populating-a-field-when-choosing-a-relate-field-suite-crm#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063014/populating-a-field-when-choosing-a-relate-field-suite-crm#_=_), I'm automatically populating some fields from the aos_products module when the user chooses a product from a related field:

editviewsdefs.php

```html
............
array (
            'name' => 'codice_prodotto',
            'studio' => 'visible',
            'label' => 'LBL_CODICE_PRODOTTO',
            'displayParams' => 
            array (
              'field_to_name_array' => 
              array (
                'id' => 'aos_products_id_c',
                'name' => 'codice_prodotto',
                'description' => 'descrizione_c',
                'price' => 'prezzo_c',
              ),
            ),
          ),
......................
```

but how do I get the category related to that product?
In the product table I have id but the name is in another table...

Thank you so much.